# Manipulating List of Structure Array

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

I have a structure for example:

```
Structure User
 Dim Name as string
 Dim ID as Short
 Dim Email as string
End Structure
```

Now the main array declaration is : Dim Client as new list of User

This new list of array holds all the records. Now how to do the following without using loop such as :
1) I need to populate all  distinct name into combo box. If it was  string array I could have done

```
Combobox1.addrange(tmpstring.distinct.toarray)
```

However because this is a structure of a type (e.g. user) what to do ?

2) How to populate only one set of field data into array using linq. For e.g. if I do Dim A = from b in Client where b.id>0  ' then all array items are returned. How to get only id ?

Thank you.

Comment: what is `tmpstring` ?

Comment: @Greatchap  Do you need to use an array? If you make it a Class with Properties instead of fields, you can use your List(Of User) as the DataSource for your ComboBox.

Comment: exactly... use a class instead

Comment: I cannot because my application now works on the fact that its a structure and not a class. plus my knowledge on manipulating class is not so good.

Comment: @Greatchap Well, it's quite simple when you use them a bit. And it's not that different than using arrays, only much more flexible. Do you want to see what would change by using a Class instead of a Structure?

Comment: Thanks @jimi. I will try it though I thought there was an option if I used structures. Actually am reading data from a db and each table is a structure in my program.

Comment: @Greatchap In this case, you possibly won't even notice the difference. I'll make an example when I have a moment.

Comment: @Greatchap  Since I said I would, I posted an example on using both a Structure and a Class. Hope it's useful.

Comment: @jimi: Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) I am not that familiar with VB, so here is the solution in C#:

```
var names = Client
  .Select(user => user.Name)
  .Distinct();
```

[Telerik Code Converter](http://converter.telerik.com) converts this to:

```
Private names = Client.[Select](Function(user) user.Name).Distinct()
```

2) If I understand you right, you want to have an array containing the ids? You should extend your query to:

```
Dim A = from b in Client 
        where b.id>0 
        select b.id
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Point 2nd is okay however point 1 is giving error.

Comment: What kind of error? I created a small example and it works fine. From your initial post, it seems that the Properties of your `Structure` are `private`. Of course they need to be `public` to evaluate them using LINQ.

Comment: I am sorry. It is working. Thank you. By the way if I have to match multiple values then how to do for e.g. dim a = from b in client where id = 1 or id = 2 and so on if the values are too much and you don‘t want to use or.

Comment: you could create an array of ids and then use array.Contains(b.id) for example.

Answer (score 1):

A List(Of Class) (a reference type) is more flexible than a Structure (a value type).

Using a List(Of Structure):

```
Dim Clients As New List(Of User)

Structure User
    Dim Name As String
    Dim ID As Short
    Dim Email As String
End Structure

'Add some elements to it
Clients.Add(New User With {.Name = "User1", .ID = 1, .Email = "Email1"})
Clients.Add(New User With {.Name = "User2", .ID = 2, .Email = "Email2"})
Clients.Add(New User With {.Name = "User3", .ID = 3, .Email = "Email3"})
```

To fill up a ComboBox list, you could:

```
'Fill it with the whole list
ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(Clients.Select(Function(c) c.Name).ToArray)

'Or filter it using a range of values
Dim SublistClient As New List(Of User)
SublistClient.AddRange(Clients.Select(Function(c) c).Where(Function(c) (c.ID > 1 And c.ID < 3)))

ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(SublistClient.Select(Function(c) c.Name).ToArray)
```

To get the Item values when a User selects it from the list:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectionChangeCommitted
    Dim SelectedUser As User = Clients(ComboBox1.SelectedIndex)
    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, ID: {1}, Email: {2}", SelectedUser.Name, SelectedUser.ID, SelectedUser.Email)
End Sub
```

Using a List(Of Class)

```
Dim Clients As New List(Of User)

Class User
   Public Property Name As String
   Public Property ID As Short
   Public Property Email As String
End Class

  'You can add items to the list in the same way, nothing will change here
  Clients.Add(New User With {.Name = "User1", .ID = 1, .Email = "Email1"})
  Clients.Add(New User With {.Name = "User2", .ID = 2, .Email = "Email2"})
  Clients.Add(New User With {.Name = "User3", .ID = 3, .Email = "Email3"})
```

Now you can fill you ComboBox using its `.DataSource` property

```
  'Add the whole List as the ComboBox `.DataSource`
  ComboBox1.DataSource = Clients

  'Or filter it using a range of values
  ComboBox1.DataSource = (Clients.Select(Function(c) c).Where(Function(c) (c.ID > 1 And c.ID < 3))).ToList()

  'Or from a specific value up or down
  ComboBox1.DataSource = (Clients.Select(Function(c) c).Where(Function(c) c.ID > 1)).ToList()

  'This gives you extended options when you have to present your data
  'or evaluate the result of a choice
  ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name"
  ComboBox1.ValueMember = "ID"

'The user choice is evaluated more or less in the same manner
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectionChangeCommitted
   Dim SelectedUser As User = CType(ComboBox1.SelectedItem, User)
   Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, ID: {1}, Email: {2}", SelectedUser.Name, SelectedUser.ID, SelectedUser.Email)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate your help. :)